# how to make the breakpoint work in the bashdb

Tags: linux, shell, trepan

i follow this manual to lean to use the bashdb:
http://archive09.linux.com/articles/153383.html#commentthis
And when i use the bashdb to bt the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

version="0.01";

fibonacci() {
    n=${1:?If you want the nth fibonacci number, you must supply n as the first parameter.}
    if [ $n -le 1 ]; then 
    echo $n
    else
    l=`fibonacci $((n-1))`
    r=`fibonacci $((n-2))`
    echo $((l + r))
    fi
}

for i in `seq 1 10`
do
  result=$(fibonacci $i)
  echo "i=$i result=$result"
done
```

And here is the detail of the debugging:
  kaiwii@ubuntu:~/shell_test$ bash --debugger ./fibonacci.sh
    bashdb debugger, release 4.2-0.6

```
Copyright 2002, 2003, 2004, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010 Rocky Bernstein
This is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.

(/home/kaiwii/shell_test/fibonacci.sh:3):
3:  version="0.01";
bashdb<0> bt
->0 in file `./fibonacci.sh' at line 3
##1 main() called from file `./fibonacci.sh' at line 0
bashdb<1> next
(/home/kaiwii/shell_test/fibonacci.sh:16):
16: for i in `seq 1 10`
bashdb<2> list
 11:        r=`fibonacci $((n-2))`
 12:        echo $((l + r))
 13:        fi
 14:    }
 15:    
 16: => for i in `seq 1 10`
 17:    do
 18:      result=$(fibonacci $i)
 19:      echo "i=$i result=$result"
 20:    done
bashdb<3> next
(/home/kaiwii/shell_test/fibonacci.sh:18):
18:   result=$(fibonacci $i)
bashdb<4> break fibonacci
Breakpoint 1 set in file /home/kaiwii/shell_test/fibonacci.sh, line 5.
bashdb<5> continue
i=1 result=1
i=2 result=1
i=3 result=2
i=4 result=3
i=5 result=5
i=6 result=8
i=7 result=13
i=8 result=21
i=9 result=34
i=10 result=55
```

And my question is when i use the command,continue after using the command,break fibonacci
,it does stop at the beginning of the method,fibonacci but instead quit the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in bashdb (version 4.2-0.8 and below) in the handling of the "break" command.

The "next" command sets a flag that tells bash to skip over functions and the "break" command isn't clearing that.

[git sources](https://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=git&group_id=61395) have the fix, so if you can use that, this is one way to get the fix.

Another way is to find where `bashdb/lib/break.sh` is installed (let's say it is in `/usr/share/lib/bashdb/lib/break.sh`) and with the patch below saved in `/tmp/bashdb.patch`

```
--- bashdb/lib/break.sh
+++ bashdb/lib/break.sh
@@ -218,6 +218,11 @@ _Dbg_set_brkpt() {
     typeset dq_source_file
     dq_source_file=$(_Dbg_esc_dq "$source_file")
     typeset dq_condition=$(_Dbg_esc_dq "$condition")
+
+    # Make sure we are not skipping over functions.
+    _Dbg_old_set_opts="$_Dbg_old_set_opts -o functrace"
+    _Dbg_write_journal_eval "_Dbg_old_set_opts='$_Dbg_old_set_opts'"
+
     _Dbg_write_journal_eval "_Dbg_brkpt_line[$_Dbg_brkpt_max]=$lineno"
     _Dbg_write_journal_eval "_Dbg_brkpt_file[$_Dbg_brkpt_max]=\"$dq_source_file\""
     _Dbg_write_journal "_Dbg_brkpt_cond[$_Dbg_brkpt_max]=\"$dq_condition\""
```

And then run as root:

```
 # cd /usr/share/lib
 # patch -p0 < /tmp/bashdb.patch
```

Comment: i try the second way,but the patch prompt such mistake,like:kaiwii@ubuntu:/usr/share/bashdb/lib$ sudo patch -p0 < /tmp/bashdb.patch 
[sudo] password for kaiwii: 
patching file bashdb/lib/break.sh
Hunk #1 FAILED at 218.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file bashdb/lib/break.sh.rej

Comment: The patch should be self-explanatory -- there are some lines that get added. Find the file, edit it, and add the lines. For you I feel also compelled to add: save the file after you edit it.